# Magento 2, website redirecting to localhost

Tags: magento2, cache, server-setup, localhost

I uploaded my magento 2 website from localhost (xampp) to server.

I changed base url in database table but it is still redirecting to same localhost (both section frontend and admin).

Is there a problem with the cache? If yes, then how do I clear the cache on server?

Comment: clear your webshop cache from var/cache or rename cache directory.

Comment: See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html

Comment: Already removed all files but still redirecting.

Answer (score 5):

moving files and database

I assume these two steps are obvious:

copy all of your local files to production server

dump your magento local db and import it into your production server db

editing in production server

now on your production server you need to follow these two steps:

edit app/etc/local.xml file and change database info

in production db,in its core_config_data table, you should find every records containing the url of your local installation, then you need to update those values;which can be found with this query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `core_config_data`
 WHERE `value` LIKE 'http://example.com';
```

edit (thanks to comments):

3. Do not forget to delete var folder contents
4. it'd better if you remove the content of app/etc/use_cache.ser too

you can clear cache by

go to cpanel

cpanel > filemanager > public_html > var > cache

select all cache

delete all

other way is

Through the Magento Admin Panel

Log in to your Admin Panel account
 Go to the System -> Cache Management section
 Click on the Flush Magento Cache button

Using SSH/FTP or the cPanel File Manager

Delete the contents of the var/cache/ folder using the following SSH command (MUST be executed from your Magento base directory):

rm -rf var/cache/*

OR

Delete the folder var/cache/ through your FTP client or using the cPanel File Manager.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Already removed all files but still redirecting. it is magento 2 project.

Comment: are you sure you change both url in core_config_data for secure and non-secure???

Comment: yes.. I have already updated.

Comment: clear all cache and sessions. and clear browser history also.

Comment: update local.xml for database also.

Comment: magento version is 2.0
I cleared all cache and sessions. I tried it in different different systems problem is in all system.

Comment: Its my website where problem exists:
http://www.website-design-perth.com.au/

Comment: check local.xml twise and url in database. this two only redirect.

Comment: I did it in database. but
local.xml is not present in Magento 2 themes anymore.

Documentation about new Magento 2 layout structure can be read here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html

Comment: check proper permission for files and folders.

Comment: permissions are:
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;                        // 644 permission for files

 find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

Comment: also give 777 to app/etc folder

Comment: done. app/etc folder given to 777. But the problem still remain same.

Answer (score 5):

update values using built-in console commands (substitute your domain name):

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://awesome-domain.dot/"

php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://awesome-dom.dot/"

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems Magento 2 has a default hostname "localhost" somewhere. Normally you should be able to run Magento 2 without setting the Base URL. But I've just encountered various instances (Magento 2.0.4) that suddenly redirected to localhost. The solution was to edit the `core_config_data` table directly and insert a new `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` with the correct URL set. After installing Magento 2, the Admin Panel should give you a message repeatedly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to clear comment before this line in php.ini file:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

to

```
 extension=php_intl.dll
for your problem
```

> Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /home/energys5/public_html/website-design-perth.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 107
>
> please check first following php extension on your sever curl. dom.
>
> mcrypt.
>
> simplexml.
>
> spl.
>
> xsl.
>
> intl.
>
> mbstring.
>
> ctype.
>
> hash.
>
> openssl.
>
> zip.
>
> xmlwriter.
>
> gd.
>
> iconv.
>
> and PHP 5.5.x and greater versions
>
> MySQL 5.6.x and greater versions  and file permissions

```
 "{"path":"directorypath/app/etc"}"   writable directory permission.

"{"path":"directorypat/var"}" writable directory permission.

"{"path":"directorypath/pub/media"}" writable directory permission.

"{"path":"directorypath/pub/static"}" writable directory permission.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename your .htaccess.sample to .htaccess and try

or

2. You can put your demo magento2 .htaccess file and try.